# Why does Node.js ignore my PowerShell ExecutionPolicy setting?

Tags: node.js, powershell

I have a [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) application where I'm trying to call [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell):

```
var app = require('express')(),
    child_process = require('child_process');

app.post('/deploy', function(req, res) {

    var errors = '';
    var child = child_process.spawn('powershell.exe', ['deploy.ps1']);

    child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        errors += data;
    });

    child.stderr.on('end', function() {
        if (errors) {
            console.log('Error:');
            console.log(errors);
        }
    })

    child.on('exit', function(code) {
        console.log('Powershell Script finished');
        if (!!code)
            console.log('I think it failed');
        else
            console.log('I think it worked.')
    });

    child.stdin.end();

    res.end('');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

When I run it (regardless of whether the .ps1 file exists or not), I get the following:

```
File C:\Users\jkodroff.INTERNAL.000\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because
the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:2
+ . <<<<  'C:\Users\jkodroff.INTERNAL.000\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

File C:\Users\jkodroff.INTERNAL.000\Code\gitpulldeploy.js\deploy.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is
disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:13
+ .\deploy.ps1 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

I have verified that `get-executionpolicy` returns `unrestricted`, so what gives?

**Bonus Question** How am I going to get around this same problem once I'm hosting this process in [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)?

**Update**
This does not work:
`var child = child_process.spawn('powershell.exe', ['-ExecutionPolicy bypass', '.\\deploy.ps1']);`

Neither does this:
Set the executionpolicy to `unrestriected` in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`, then do 
`var child = child_process.spawn('powershell.exe', ['.\\deploy.ps1']);`

But this **does** work at the command line:
`powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\deploy.ps1`

Comment: There is a 64-bit PowerShell and a 32-bit PowerShell. Did you set both? If not, node.js is probably launching the one you didn't change.

Comment: Added some stuff I tried.  No dice.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I'm running into the same issue with spawning Powershell script from Node.  I setup my machine's policy's via command line, but nothing works from NodeJS

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to run the PowerShell script in a different execution environment (x86/x64) than the one in which you set the execution policy to unrestricted.

The easy fix is to add the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` to the PowerShell command line. This will bypass the execution policy and execute scripts.

Comment: Do you know how to do it from node?

Comment: What you did should have been right. Did it give you the same error? It's possible that PowerShell is handling the command line arguments in a way that doesn't match with node.js passing them. Try instead `var child = child_process.exec('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass .\deploy.ps1', callback /* you provide the callback */);`